# How to limit the output response of html(info) in a serialized Ajax .post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, serialization

I'm using this form and jquery post snippet (with the self-posting form below)

```
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');?>">
   <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
   <button id="submit">Submit</button> 
</form>
<div id="results"></div>

 <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#username").blur(function() {
       if ($('#username').val() != '' ) {
          $.post( $("#form1").attr("action"), 
                  $("#form1 :input").serializeArray(),
                  function(info){ 
                        $("#results").html(info);
                  });
        }
     });

   });
 </script>
```

with php

```
 etc...
 $numRows = $stmt->rowCount();
 if($numRows > 0) echo '<strong class="dred">Hey, you\'re already registered.</strong>';
 if($numRows < 1) echo '<strong class="dgreen">O.K.</strong>';
```

to check if a username exists in the database, and to put the correct message into #results.

It works, but in #results, the response also includes the form input field and submit button again.
 How do I change this function to limit the data that goes into #results, to just the message as designated. Thanks, I'm still a noob with Ajax.

```
 function(info) {$("#results").html(info);});
```

Comment: There is no form in `#results` div and your PHP response does not return any form either. Please elaborate more on what you expect. Do you want to hide the form upon submission or something? Also there are syntax errors in this statement: `function(info) {$("#results").html(info;}); `

Comment: Are you echoing a form from your PHP? If not, you have some other issues.

Comment: @Thanks, let me adjust it

Comment: @Jay Blanchard - I'm not trying to echo a form, it is on its own and I'm trying to re-write it so it won't.

Comment: @Victor Levin - Did the edit make it clearer what the problem is. What I want it to do is to echo one of the two messages in the php snip, either 'you're already registered'  or ' O.K.'. but the actual echo is giving me the correct message, but then also the form input field and the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are doing ajax to the same file where the form itself is there, you are getting the response with the form fields including the result.

You should do ajax to  different file where you should only perform the db query and return the result.

```
<!-- ajax code -->
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#username").blur(function() {
       if ($('#username').val() != '' ) {
          $.post( "some_other_file.php", 
                  $("#form1 :input").serializeArray(),
                  function(info){ 
                        $("#results").html(info);
                  });
        }
     });

   });
 </script>

 <!-- php code -->
 /*some_other_file.php*/

 $numRows = $stmt->rowCount();
 if($numRows > 0) echo '<strong class="dred">Hey, you\'re already registered.</strong>';
 if($numRows < 1) echo '<strong class="dgreen">O.K.</strong>';
```

Comment: Thanks, I originally had it in a second file, but I'm just learning form validation and it seemed easier to stay in the same page for all of that. Hence my tests of today... In the end, I may have to anyway.

Comment: Yup, I think I'll just knuckle down and learn form validation better. Thanks for your answer. Do you have any preferred source of information for form validation to a second php page?

Comment: @AllThisOnAnACER, For form validation I generally use regex in js, you can use regex for php also.

Comment: Now I have two problems... :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop the form from outputting when your in a form post using ajax.

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['username'])){
    //process form here and 
    if($numRows > 0) echo '<strong class="dred">Hey, you\'re already registered.</strong>';
    if($numRows < 1) echo '<strong class="dgreen">O.K.</strong>';
    exit(); //exit so no more output goes.

} 

?>

 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');?>">
 <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
 <button id="submit">Submit</button> </form><div id="results"></div>
```

The other option is to filter your HTML in the jQuery

```
$.post($("#form1").attr("action"), $("#form1 :input").serializeArray(), function(info){ 
    html = $(info).find('#results');
    $("#results").html(html);
});

<?php
//then make sure your message goes into that div
echo'<div id="results">';
if($numRows > 0) echo '<strong class="dred">Hey, you\'re already registered.</strong>';
if($numRows < 1) echo '<strong class="dgreen">O.K.</strong>';
echo'</div>';
?>
```

Comment: I'll have a look at your code and get back to you in a few minutes. Thanks.

Comment: The addition of the exit() was the answer as the second form no longer outputs, but new problem, I'm planning to have a second one of these for a different field below, and obviously exit() will prevent that. What else can I use that will have the effect of exit() but let me do  a second one below?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Ultimately I decided to use a second page to post the data to. But your answer did work for the limited question I had originally asked.